# How can I merge multiple bitmaps into one in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

For the past day I have been trying to find a way to combine some images, that are stored locally within a windows phone application, into one image. I am trying to create one image that shows all of them side by side. I can't use any third party libraries or anything due to job constrictions. I will not need to save this image as it will be shared immediately upon creation. I only need to know how to create it.  This is being done in c#, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance